# Finding the general formula for the last standing soldier

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algorithms, computer-science

Suppose there are 'n' soldiers standing in a circle who have decided to kill each other (just because they don't want to surrender to the opposition).
Lets say they are denoted from a<sub>1</sub> to a<sub>n</sub> in the clockwise direction and the first soldier (a<sub>1</sub>) kills the m<sup>th</sup> **living soldier (i.e. the dead soldiers will not be included in the counting)** next to him (a<sub>m+1</sub>) in the clockwise direction. After killing the soldier, the soldier standing next to the dead soldier (in CW direction) kills the m<sup>th</sup> soldier next to him.
So the pattern of killing goes like this:
a<sub>1</sub> kills a<sub>m+1</sub>
a<sub>m+2</sub> kills a<sub>2m+2</sub>
a<sub>2m+3</sub> kills a<sub>3m+3</sub>
and so on.
**(But this analogy is valid only for one circle, since after that the relative positions will be different with respect to their their denotations)**
**Is it possible to devise out a general formula for the last standing soldier? If yes, how can I approach this question?**

This is a broader version of the Josephus problem. In Josephus problem  where m=2.
**What I tried:**
I tried for a hit and trial method keeping 'n' constant with varying 'm' but could not observe any specific pattern.
Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sure this variant of Josephus has been handled on this website before. Please do a search for it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I searched for it but could not find any good answers or well-explained questions or probably I did not visit the question you are thinking of. Can you please link it?

Comment: http://math.fau.edu/yiu/Oldwebsites/PSRM2012/PSRM20120702.pdf

Comment: If you type *Josephus* into the search box on this page (or if you just go to https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=josephus), over 90 questions come back at you. I'm not going to go through those 90 questions to find whether there's one that gives you what you need – that's what you should do.

Comment: Also, the question has nothing to do with linear algebra, and the number-theory tag is also inappropriate.

Comment: Of course part of the point of the puzzle is that it's much easier for a smart soldier to choose position by just applying the procedure on paper, with objects, etc., rather than trying to reason out the answer. Doesn't mean we can't say anything about the problem more generally, of course.

Comment: @GerryMyerson no props! I will go thru all the questions